# C++ left shift gives a different result when shift over than bits in argument

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

 uint32_t b = 64;
 std::cout << std::hex << (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL << b) << "<< 64" << "\n";
 std::cout << std::hex << (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL << 64) << "<< 64" << "\n";
 std::cout << std::hex << (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL << 65) << "<< 65" << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

My result is:

```
ffffffffffffffff<< 64
0<< 64
0<< 65
```

I need expression on left side of shift operator and I expect zero result when shift to 64. What's wrong?

I see [When does bit shifting cause undefined behavior in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76694990/when-does-bit-shifting-cause-undefined-behavior-in-c)

before and after C++20 *"the least significant bits are filled with zeros"*, but in my case I see two different result when I use literal and when I use variable on the left side of `<<`.

Debian 12 with GCC version 12.2.0, option -std=c++2a was used when compilation.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. See the last paragraph of the accepted answer in the duplicate.

Comment: Remember that "[The result of a shift operation is undefined if the second operand is negative, or if the right operand is greater than or equal to the width in bits of the promoted left operand.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/bitwise-shift-operators?view=msvc-170)". So your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Read the final sentence of the accepted answer, it does answer your question: *In all cases, if the number of bits to shift(the right operand) is greater than or equal to the number of bits of the left operand after integer promotion, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Assuming your unsigned long long is 64-bits, the biggest value you can have for `<<` is `<< 63`.  Both 64 and 65 are bigger than 63.

Comment: Did you expect actual demons out of your nose instead of just boring numeric results?